# Free way to encode videos for Internet Explorer

Tags: video, internet-explorer

We make videos and sell them as stream on our homepage. 
We decided to use the vp9 codec, because we don't have to pay any licensing fees.

But Internet Explorer seems to support only MP4 (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp), and when we use mp4 it seems that we have to pay some fees, because it's a commercial page.

Is there any fee-free possibility to have our play our videos in IE?